# Mono audio output with pulseaudio and alsa on embedded system

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulse-audio

I am running an embedded system using pulseaudio and alsa.
I need to downmix all audio inputs to a single mono output.
I have seen other answers that involve modifying `/etc/pulse/default.pa` like the example below.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/17791/can-i-downmix-stereo-audio-to-mono

I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work while in system mode.
When I try to run the pulseaudio service as the `pulse` user it seems to be reading the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa` but I get an error: `failed to open module "module-remap-sink".`

I am OK using either ALSA or pulseaudio to achieve mono output. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Simplest way to do this might be hardware, i.e., a stereo-to-mono adapter (~US$6 or so), rather than having to reconfigure pulse each time you need to change back and forth.

Comment: Hello! Because this is an embedded system, it is not a great option.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to solve the issue using alsa and creating a file at `/home/root/.asoundrc`

This was helpful
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=33431

Comment: It would help others if you edited your answer to include the essential parts from the link. Links may disappear in the future.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).